# Is it important to use InitializeLifetimeService for windows service members

Tags: c#, object-lifetime, lifetime

Does I have to set the `InitializeLifetimeService` on the members that should be running as long as my application or service is running? by example of my own experience Because I build some services with a timers but the timers stop working after a couple of days.